# Drawing glove for iPad

Tags: ipad, hardware-recommendation, drawing

I'd really like to draw more on my iPad but I like to rest my hand on the screen doing so, which registers as a stroke along with the pen.

I've been looking around for a proper gadget for this problem, some kind of drawing glove for the iPad, but haven't found any.

I tried a couple of gloves myself but they're either too thick (clumsy) or too thin (hand registers with screen).

Anyone here drawing frequently on the iPad with a good DIY glove suggestion or link to a product?

Answer (score 3):

From a [FAQ of Smudge Guard](http://www.smudgeguard.com/faq.htm):

> Unfortunately, the current SG gloves are not compatible with the iPad
>   at all. The SG glove does not prevent detection on the iPad. :(
>
> However, please note that recently, two other customers of mine bought
>   the SG glove and tested it while sketching on the Autodesk Sketchbook
>   Pro. They said it did not prevent accidental strokes with their palm
>   because the material/fabric was not thick enough. But cleverly, my two
>   other customers then **tried slipping in a microfiber cloth**, (folded in
>   half) into the side of the glove. The microfiber they used, were those
>   little rectangular shaped cloths that are made to clean eyeglasses.
>   They inserted it into the glove (where the edge of the hand is) and
>   they said it worked! The **iPad didn't detect the side of their hand**.

There is also an info they started working on a fully-iPad compatible glove. Microfiber option could work with any thin glove, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried bikers' gloves (the fingerless kind)?

Or, take your thick gloves and cut the fingers off (maybe leaving the pinky finger). This should give you your manual dexterity (fingers are free) but the iPad won't detect your hand.

Comment: Yeah I tried a weight lifting glove which is rather thick, somehow the screen still registered from the hand. Not very often, but enough to distract. Currently I'm using what you suggest with cut off fingers on an ordinary glove. Works OK when home, but the glove is quite thick giving quite a distance from the screen. I wonder if there are any materials that are thin and completely removes the capacitivity, would be quite easy to stitch together a palm side + pinky cover.

Comment: Try a sheet of metal (like some sort of conductive foil) that touches neither your hand nor the screen to make a bit of a Faraday cage. I've not idea if that'll work or not, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Now there is one: TheHandGlider.com
Although I made my own: take a pair of trouser socks in the women's section at Target (around $7). Double them up, leave one side intact to hold one or two fingers (I left it big enough for two fingers because of resting my ring and pinky on the screen) cut off the rest so your other fingers are free, and sew it up. The double thickness did the job, plus it kinda cleans my screen as I move along...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Smudge Guard](http://www.smudgeguard.com/)? I've heard a few recommendations regarding this product and iPad drawing.

A quick search brings up a recommendation on a art forum: http://www.penciljack.com/forum/showthread.php?114705-Drawing-on-the-ipad-using-gloves

Comment: Smudge Guard is not compatible with the iPad unfortunately. The hand still registers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try ordinary rubber washing-up gloves with the fingers amputated. I'm pretty sure they wouldn't let any capacitative surface register your hand.

The only issue I could foresee is that they might get a bit sweaty and horrible.

Answer (score 0):

The new iPad mini and iOS 6 have a much better hand detection algorithm, but I find myself able to both hold the device and draw without needing gloves. Even though I haven't seen Apple advertise it - my third generation iPad also ignores a hand or part of a hand and the digitizer isn't affected by my wrist like it was on earlier OS.

Have you evaluated your drawing app on the new OS?

Answer (score 0):

You guys, I made one very easily and it only cost me 2$! I bought a pair of black stretchy gloves (the cheap ones you find at gas stations and grocery stores ) and simply cut off the thumb - ring fingers leaving only the pinky. I cut them just below the 2nd knuckle so they don't tear and then used a. Lighter to seal the cuts so they won't thread out. It works so freaking good and doesn't look too weird either. I'm now using my adonit stylus with ease. Try it!!

Answer (score 0):

Update as of 2018: Get an [Apple Pencil](https://www.apple.com/apple-pencil/)! (:

Unfortunately, this **only works with the iPad Pro**.

The iPad Pro has built-in palm-rejection with the Pencil that works quite well, no need for gloves.

Answer (score -1):

Take a regular garden glove and cut off the tips of the fingers, and sew extra fabric to the palms.